# Connection refused trying to connect to mongoDB docker instance

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to deploy a simple app with a MongoDB with JPA, but I can't make it work right.

When I deploy the app in a docker container, I keep getting the following error:

```
2020-10-05 18:47:39.770 INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

This is the dockerfile I use to build the image:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml I used to run mongoDB:

```yaml
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

My entities all follow the following pattern (being  the name of the entity):

```java
@Document
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class <Name>Entity {
    @Id
    private Integer <Name>Id;
    // More data
}
```

And my JPA Repositories (as above, being  the name of the jpa class & entity):

```java
public interface <Name>JPA extends MongoRepository<<Name>Entity, Integer>{
}
```

And finally, I have defined the following properties under application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=api-database
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=example
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
```

I am able to connect to localhost:8081 to see the mongo-express interface, but appart from that, I don't see anything.

Comment: Had the same exception, but I was mapping mongodb port to 26000 and I was able to connect to db on this port from the outside, but in docker-compose my spring app still has to use the default 27017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can't connect via loopback address because mongodb and the app are in different containers. They're like like different machines and `localhost` for each of them is not the host, but the container itself. Use service name (from `docker-compose.yml`) instead:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo:27017
```

Comment: Also, I had to put the port in the host property, instead of defining another property for it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Had the same problem. Using "mongo:27017" as the host property resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you edit the application.priperties file ?
Like this :- spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo:27017 ?
I have the same problem
When I try to launch mongo from the docker it gives me the below connnection url :-
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to connect with containerized MongoDB docker instance with localhost then you might face this issue.

**Solution :**

In place of

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

To connect the host out of the box by using the special DNS name: **host.docker.internal**

```
mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017
```

Replacing **localhost** with **host.docker.internal** will do the trick.

Comment: it does not work when i try to connect from local application